# Different behavior between script executed using C++ call and using cmd prompt

Tags: c++, batch-file, openssl

I've this script called otp.bat

```
REM @echo off
REM File paths
SET "DVRPRIVKEY=%~dp0dvrprivkey.der"
SET "DVRPUBKEY=%~dp0dvrpubkey.der"
SET "SERVERPUBKEY=%~dp0server_public_key.der"

SET "SHAREDSECRET=%~dp0sharedsecret.bin"
SET "PLAINTEXT=%~dp0plaintext.txt"
SET "ENCRYPTEDTEXT=%~dp0enctext.enc"
SET "DECRYPTEDTEXT=%~dp0dectext.txt"

REM Check the input parameter
IF "%~1"=="start" goto start
IF "%~1"=="stop" goto stop
IF "%~1"=="restart" goto restart
IF "%~1"=="encrypt" goto encrypt
IF "%~1"=="decrypt" goto decrypt
goto usage

:start
echo starting otp, generating new ephemeral keys

openssl genpkey -algorithm X25519 -outform DER -out "%DVRPRIVKEY%"
openssl pkey -inform DER -in "%DVRPRIVKEY%" -outform DER -pubout -out "%DVRPUBKEY%"
goto :eof
```

it works if I call it using command prompt in windows.
I created a C++ program to call it using a system call.

```
const int scriptResult = system(".\\otp\\otp.bat start");

if (scriptResult != 0) {
    CRS_LOG(error) << "Error executing " << ".\\otp\\otp.bat start";
    return false;
}
```

in log, I can confirm that it has been executed (I also try with returning 0 in fail case and 1 if script has been executed, and it returned 1).

The difference is that when I call the script using C++ function, it doesn't create the couple of keys.

The code works in debug mode (launch it using VS19) but doesn't work in release mode on Windows 10  (but in  works called by cmd prompt).

details:

I modified remote script insert a pause command, this affect the result so I suppose script is called. No windows appears if I call script with C++ program.

I also try with absolute path but nothing changed.

If there are more details you need please comment.

Comment: A simple guess: The `%PATH%` is different so the `openssl` commands are not found?

Comment: the script works good if called in cmd prompt

Comment: When running from inside the IDE the environment variables, including `%PATH%` might be different. *And* they may also differ between release and debug builds.

Comment: I modified the script to just create an empty file, and it has been created with command prompt but not created with c++

Comment: You also have to keep track of the [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). When running from inside the IDE it might not be what you expect, and the script might not create the file in the location you think. And as before, it might differ between the debug and release settings in your IDE.

Comment: also tried with absolute path, but no changes

Comment: If you just `echo` anything in your script, is it written to the console of the running program? Or does `system` open a new console? Will any output be written there?

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to add all crucial details.

Comment: System does not open a new console, so echo not possible. I modified script with pause command and it affects the result, so I suppose script is called.

Comment: SOme way to get keys without write its on external file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254611/discussion-between-massimo-and-some-programmer-dude).